# pdflatex custom command for texstudio only run in cmd

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I've just installed MikTex by which TexStudio came aswell as the editor. So far the editor seems fine. My only problem arises once I have to compile and actually look at what I've created.

For now every time I compile something it goes into my C:\users\myname folder. But my tex file is saved under C:\Development\latexWorkspace under the name helloWorld.tex.

I've read through some forums and found out i could do

```
pdflatex -aux-directory=C:\Development\latexWorkspace -output-directory=C:\Development\latexWorkspace C:\Development\latexWorkspace\helloWorld.tex
```

So I thought, hey I just change the build in execution of pdflatex in TexStudio.
So i changed that command under Options > Configure TexStudio > Commands > PdfLatex to

```
pdflatex -aux-directory=C:\Development\LatexWorkspace -output-directory=C:\Development\LatexWorkspace %.tex
```

However i was just given the message:

Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -aux-directory=C:\Development\LatexWorkspace -output-directory=C:\Development\LatexWorkspace "HelloWorld".tex

I even copied that Error right into CMD and it ran just fine as expected.

Can it be that TexStudio use a custom shell to run commands or such?
How can i make it output everything to that folder of mine I want it to?

Comment: Problem solved, Just had to change C:\Development\LatexWorkspace to C:\\Development\\LatexWorkspace, didn't thought the backslash would do it tho, apparently i forgot the program will handle it as a string, while the cmd apparently dont

Comment: You should write up an answer so it can benefit future visitors to the site.

Comment: TeXstudio doesn't use any shell to execute the commands, but the "are executed directly" (whatever that means), according to [TeXstudio : User manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OPs comment converted to an answer]

Just had to change `C:\Development\LatexWorkspace` to `C:\\Development\\LatexWorkspace`.